# (React Native) TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation')

Tags: javascript, react, react-native, react-navigation, react-router

Não consigo resolver este erro.. **alguém me ajuda**

Eu clico no botão para ir para outra pág e ele aparece.. segue o código:

[Esse é o código do componente menu, nele tem uma lista de botões com essa estrutura]

O mesmo componente está com essa estrutura..

`const Menu = () => {...}`

[Estrutura dos botões]

```
            <TapGestureHandler>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard')}>
                    <AntDesign name="home" size={35} color="#fff" />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </TapGestureHandler>
```

`

[Arquivo routers] Claro tem mais telas, só coloquei uma, mas as outras estão iguais, ai depois tem um createSwitchNagivation e dentro eu chamo essa Stack e dps eu dou um export

`const Stack = createStackNavigator({
    Dashboard: {
        screen: Dashboard,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerShown: false,
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Talvez se trate do modo que exportou tua página para a rota, vou reescrever o código te mostrar como construir a rota e a página conforme as novas api do react navigation e do próprio react.
1. cria arquivos separados para as telas, para ficar melhor o exemplo
2. coloca a rota no app.js

resolvendo por meio de função:

```
     import React from 'react'
     import * from 'react-native'
     import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'

   export default function SuaPágina(){
     const navigation = useNavigation() // Novo hoock
           return( 
            <View>
            <TapGestureHandler>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => 
                       navigation.navigate('Dashboard')}>
                    <AntDesign name="home" size={35} color="#fff" />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </TapGestureHandler>
             </View>
            )}
```

arquivo da sua rota:

```
    import React from 'react'
    import SuaPágina from '.../
    import createStackNavigator from '@react-navigation/stack'
    import NavigationContainer from '@react-navigation/native'


   const Stack = createStackNavigator()

   export default  function App(){

    return(

       <NavigationContainer> 
             <Stack.Navigator>
                   <Stack.Screen  name='Nome da Tela' 
                    component={página que tu exportou}/>
                   <Stack.Screen name='DashBoard'
                    component={página Dashboard}/>
             </Stack.Navigator>           
       </NavigationContainer>
     )       
   }
```